# Java Checkbox List Selection Listener

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcheckbox

I have code for making a checkbox list. However, if I click anywhere on a row the checkbox selection changes. I want this to only happen when **the checkbox itself** is clicked. How do I correct this listener to be "accurate"?

Here is a [`SSCCE`](http://sscce.org/):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class CheckBoxList extends JList
{
    public CheckBoxList()
    {
        super();

        setModel(new DefaultListModel<>());
        setCellRenderer(new CheckboxCellRenderer());

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
            {
                int index = locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());

                if (index != -1)
                {
                    Object object = getModel().getElementAt(index);

                    if (object instanceof JCheckBox)
                    {
                        JCheckBox checkbox = (JCheckBox) object;

                        checkbox.setSelected(!checkbox.isSelected());
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        listModel.addElement("Element 1");
        listModel.addElement("Element 2");
        JList<String> list = new JList<>();
        list.setCellRenderer(new CheckboxListCellRenderer<>());
        list.setModel(listModel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(list);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CheckboxCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer
{
    private static Border noFocusBorder = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
                                                  boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        if (value instanceof CheckBoxListEntry)
        {
            CheckBoxListEntry checkbox = (CheckBoxListEntry) value;
            checkbox.setBackground(isSelected ? list.getSelectionBackground() : list.getBackground());
            if (checkbox.isRed())
            {
                checkbox.setForeground(Color.red);
            } else
            {
                checkbox.setForeground(isSelected ? list.getSelectionForeground() : list.getForeground());
            }
            checkbox.setEnabled(isEnabled());
            checkbox.setFont(getFont());
            checkbox.setFocusPainted(false);
            checkbox.setBorderPainted(true);
            checkbox.setBorder(isSelected ? UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder") : noFocusBorder);

            return checkbox;
        } else
        {
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value.getClass().getName(), index,
                    isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    }
}

class CheckBoxListEntry extends JCheckBox
{
    public CheckBoxListEntry(Object itemValue, boolean selected)
    {
        super(itemValue == null ? "" : "" + itemValue, selected);
    }

    public boolean isSelected()
    {
        return super.isSelected();
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected);
    }

    boolean isRed()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider placing a container (like a vertical Box) holding JCheckBoxes in a JScrollPane instead.  Your design won’t work for users who prefer keyboard input over mouse input, and it is misleading, since it acts differently from actual JCheckBoxes, which do in fact allow mouse input on any part of their text as well as on their icon.

Comment: @VGR:
Alright, sounds tedious but might work. Is there no listener that fires just on clicks at the `JCheckBox` itself?

Comment: Why not use a `JTable` with a suitable `CellEditor`?